# How to get a secure connection with mattermost on AWS using ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, https, ansible, mattermost

I am trying to set up HTTPS on mattermost on AWS using ansible.  However, I keep getting:

```
This site can not provide a secure connection
```

When I go check the logs of mattermost I see that:

```
TLS handshake error from (MYIP): acme/autocert: missing server name","source":"httpserver"}
```

My config file shows:

```
Service_SiteURL: "https://(MYIP):443"
Service_LicenseFileLocation: ""
Service_ListenAddress: ":443"
Service_ConnectionSecurity: "TLS"
Service_TLSCertFile: ""
Service_TLSKeyFile: ""
Service_UseLetsEncrypt: "true"
Service_LetsEncryptCertificateCacheFile: "./config/letsencrypt.cache"
Service_Forward80To443: "true"
```

I am not sure what to do, can someone help me?

Comment: The problem here doesn't actually have anything to do with neither AWS nor with ansible, right? It's just a Mattermost configuration problem, correct?

Comment: Also, you are doing two things at once above: 1. configuring Mattermost 2. configuring Letsencrypt. Do one thing after the other: first configure Mattermost. Once that works, configure Letsencrypt.